# tensorflow installation error in Window + anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, installation, anaconda

i tried to install tensorflow in my anaconda by creating a virtual env

```
 conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

[image]

but after i type y, nothing happened. How can i fix this?

Comment: When you say *nothing happened*, does it hang up or do you get back to the command prompt? As @LYu says, your command creates a new environment called `tensorflow` and installs Python 3.5 in it, but it doesn't actually install tensorflow unless you also specify that i.e. `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 tensorflow`. But I'm not clear yet whether conda is working for you at all.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Answer (score 0):

So what you did is creating an environment called `tensorflow`, you need to install it as well

you can do either

`conda install tensorflow`

or

`pip install tensorflow`

Comment: If you're using a conda environment and the package you want is available from a conda repository, you're much better off using `conda install`.

Comment: @nekomatic Agreed. But for `tensorflow` the version available for conda was 1.1 when I checked it last time.. which missed lots of stuff